# Let $X$ be a Moore space and $e(X)=\omega$. Is it metrizable?

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

Let $X$ be a Moore space and $e(X)=\omega$. Is it metrizable?

**What I've tried:** I list these facts:

> 1 A space $X$ is a Moore space iff $X$ is a $\sigma$-space and a $p$-space.
>
> 2 If $X$ is a $p$-space, then $nw(X)=w(X)$.
>
> 3 A space $X$ is a $\sigma$-space if $X$ has a $\sigma$-discrete network.

Since if $X$ is a $\sigma$-space  and $e(X)=\omega$, we know that $nw(X)=\omega$, [see the proof](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/412795/does-x-have-countable-network-if-it-has-countable-extent). So by 2, we can conclude that $w(X)=nw(X)=\omega$, and hence it is metrizable.

However I'm not sure. Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here are the references.

A Moore space is a *regular* developable space. [Gru, 1.3] A space $X$ is a $\sigma$-space if $X$ has a $\sigma$-discrete network. [Gru, 4.3] Every Moore space $X$ is a $\sigma$-space. [Gru, 4.5] Moreover, a space $X$ is a Moore space iff $X$ is a $\sigma$-space and a $p$-space (or a $w\Delta$-space). [Gru, 4.7.(i)] If $X$ is a $\sigma$-space  and $e(X)=\omega$, we know that $nw(X)=\omega$, [see the proof](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/412795/does-x-have-countable-network-if-it-has-countable-extent/412860#412860). If $X$ is a $p$-space, then $nw(X)=w(X)$. [Gru, 4.2] By Nagata-Smirnov Theorem [Eng, 4.4.7], a topological space $X$ is metrizable iff $X$ is regular and has a $\sigma$-locally finite base. In particular, a regular second countable space is metrizble.

**References**

[Eng] Ryszard Engelking. *General Topology* (Russian version, 1986).

[Gru] Gary Gruenhage, *[Generalized Metric Spaces](http://webfile.ru/6475714)*, in K. Kunen and J. E. Vaughan, Handbook of set theoretic topology, Elsevier, 1984.

Comment: Do you think the proof is all right?

Comment: Yes, I think so.

Comment: Is there a reference which has proved this result?

Comment: I found no such references.